# Could not deduce (Functor r) from (MonadRandom r)

Tags: haskell

The simple following code

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Random

psum :: (MonadRandom r) => Int -> r Double -> r Double
psum n x = fmap sum $ replicateM n x
```

yields the error:

```
Could not deduce (Functor r) arising from a use of `fmap'
    from the context (MonadRandom r)
```

This is weird to me because of

```
class (Monad m) => MonadRandom m where ...
```

in `Control.Monad.Random.Class` source file, and since monads are functors, GHC should have deduced that `r` is a functor in my context. I also tried to import `Control.Monad.Random.Class` with no success.

Adding manually the `Functor` constraint on `r` works, but I find this quite ugly.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theoretically monads are functors, but sadly `Functor` is not a superclass of `Monad` for no good reason.

Instead of adding `Functor r` you can also use `liftM` instead of `fmap`.

Edit: There really seems to be no good reason. The classes were introduced together in [Haskell 1.3](http://www.ki.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/doc/html/Haskell1.3/preludechanges.html#monad-class), and superclasses already existed and were used for `MonadPlus` and `MonadZero`.

Comment: Aha. I'm doing too much mathematics. Thank you sir.